# Would bobsleds go faster if the tracks were coated in butter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, material-science, ice

Would bobsleds go faster if the ice tracks (and perhaps the bobsled blades as well) were first coated in butter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bobsleds go faster the harder (and cooler) the ice beneath it is. That is, the more slippery the surface, the higher the speed the bobsled can attain. And ice is slippery because there is a thin layer of water on it (the surface of the bobsled must also be very smooth).

So what would happen if we used butter instead of ice? Well if you freeze butter, it will still never have a layer of ice on its surface (if the butter is on the track) which is crucial for speed (minimising friction). This would slow it down.

If we kept frozen butter on the base of the bobsled, we may go just as fast (or faster, but unlikely).

And if you could use non-frozen butter (which would probably freeze anyway due to the ambient temperature) on the bobsled base, this will melt the ice, making it go slower as explained above. Also, this non-frozen butter would have a higher viscosity than the water on the ice which would also cause it to slow it down. The same would apply for non-frozen butter on the track.

Comment: That's very interesting, I never would have guessed that. Is there any other type of substance that would help (motor oil, lard, graphene, salt, alcohol, small ball bearings, etc), or is metal blade on pure ice already optimized for speed?